How to sort result when i use search params in ransack rails gem?
Hello i've working on a rails app ( a marketplace for sports teachers )
For moment its work well when i use only sort like this :
http://localhost:3000/capsules?q%5Bs%5D=price_cents+asc
http://localhost:3000/capsules?q%5Bs%5D=price_cents+desc
But when i use search params result work good but "sorting results don't work"

In my view modal for searching and sorting, i have :

<%= search_form_for @ransack_capsules, as: :capsules_search, url: capsules_path do |f| %>
   some search query like ....
   
   f.search_field :address_i_cont ....
   f.country_select :country_code_eq ...
   and others
<% end %>

<%= sort_link(@q, :starts_at, 'started at' %> 

This sort work in index BUT NOT when its used with search params.

My index action in controller look like this:

def index
    @q = Capsule.ransack(params[:q])

    @capsules = Capsule.upcoming.geocoded

    @ransack_capsules = Capsule.upcoming.ransack(params[:q])
    
    if params[:capsules_search]
      @ransack_capsules = Capsule.upcoming.ransack(params[:capsules_search], search_key: :capsules_search)
    end

    @pagy, @capsules = pagy(@ransack_capsules.result.includes(:category), items: 6, anchor_string: 'data-turbo="false"')
  end

I know its a problem in my controller but im lost ^^
I need a solution to sort results when params[:capsules_search] is used ??
